# Javascript Error: win1 is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

this is my function;

```
function ButtonClickAction3 (zEvent) {  

    var var4 = prompt ("text");
    var var1 = prompt ("text")
    var var2 = prompt ("text");
    var var3 = prompt ("text");

    win1 = window.open("MYURL1,"", "win1", "width=100,height=100,resizable");
    setTimeout("win1.close()",500);
    win2 = window.open("MYURL2,"", "win2", "width=100,height=100,resizable");
    setTimeout("win2.close()",500);
    win3 = window.open("MYURL3,"", "win3", "width=100,height=100,resizable");
    setTimeout("win3.close()",500);

}
```

When I use this code with greasemonkey;

`win1 = window.open("MYURL,"", "win1", "width=100,height=100,resizable");`

after window1 opened "win1.close()" command not work for it. İt says "win1 is not defined".

But when I open a window with this code from console;

```
win1 = window.open("MYURL1,"", "win1", "width=100,height=100,resizable");
```

win1 became defined, and I can close it with `win1.close()`

How can I use that with greasemonkey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to give your `win1` variable scope with the `var` keyword. Second, it is a good practice to pass in your functions as functions and not strings to be `eval()`'d

Try this:

```
var var4 = prompt ("text");
var var1 = prompt ("text");
var var2 = prompt ("text");
var var3 = prompt ("text");

var win1 = window.open("MYURL1", "win1", "width=100,height=100,resizable");
setTimeout(function(){win1.close();},500);

var win2 = window.open("MYURL2", "win2", "width=100,height=100,resizable");
setTimeout(function(){win2.close();},500);

var win3 = window.open("MYURL3", "win3", "width=100,height=100,resizable");
setTimeout(function(){win3.close();},500);
```

Comment: `"it is a good practice to pass in your functions as functions and not strings"` -- Actually, that is a requirement for Greasemonkey scripts, due to the sandbox security.

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with such syntax to be on the safe path always:

```
window["win1"] = window.open(...);
```

Then to close it:

```
if (window["win1"])
    window["win1"].close();
```

By assigning the variable to the `window` you force it to have global scope.